# How do I delete Minecraft Mods?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I try to delete my minecraft mods, but they just won't go away. I have tried everything, and I don't know what to do. They just won't go. I press delete, but they stay there.

How do I delete Minecraft Mods?

Comment: You're going to need to give us some more information. What mods are you using, how did you install them, what have you tried... some information about the version of Minecraft that you are using couldn't hurt either.

Comment: adding to what @Ben said we need to know if you used Forge, if so it's just a matter of changing your profile in the launcher (that way you don't have to remove your mods)

Answer (score 2):

What you could do it you have Windows is click on the start button and then search run.  Click on the secound option.  Then search apps.  Next go roaming then .minecraft then mods and you should see all your mods.  Click the one you want to delete and press delete or backspace.

Comment: I think your missing a step in your answer or your answer is incorrect. i am on Windows, i clicked the start button, i searched run but Run was not my first option and if i try to search for "roaming" in the Run dialog i get an error saying *"Windows cannot find 'roaming'. Make sure you typed the name correct;y, and then try again."*

Comment: Whoops yeah sorry about that search apps then go to the folder roaming.    As for run being the first one it might be because i've used it so much.  Sry i'll fix that.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the server isn't running, because files in use can't be deleted.  Shut it down, delete mods, start it back up.